# ImageIcon + ImageIcon = ImageIcon

Tags: java, graphics

I have two ImageIcons and I want to create a third ImageIcon which has nr 2 drawn upon nr 1.
How would I best do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code takes an `Image` from two `ImageIcon`s and creates a new `ImageIcon`.

The image from the second `ImageIcon` is drawn on top of the image from the first, then the resulting image is used to make a new `ImageIcon`:

```
Image img1 = imageIcon1.getImage();
Image img2 = imageIcon2.getImage();

BufferedImage resultImage = new BufferedImage(
    img1.getWidth(null), img1.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = resultImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();

ImageIcon resultImageIcon = new ImageIcon(resultImage);
```

**Edit**
(Fixed some errors, added transparency support.)

For allowing transparency, the `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` can be used for the image type in the constructor, rather than `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` which does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: That is pretty close, the new image seems to have a black background instead of a transparent one

Comment: Changed the type to TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR and that took care of the alpha. Many thanks